# OS X: programmatically connect to wifi in macOS apps

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm kind of new to macOS app development. I saw in other posts that you can use [`NEHotspotConfigurationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager) to connect to WIFI inside iOS applications. It is not listed in the availability section. Is it possible to do it in macOS applications?

I know that wifi can be changed with the menu bar, but our application has the top menu bar disabled to hide unwanted functionalities for our specific use case.

Any ideas are welcome! Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [CoreWLAN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan) to achieve this =)

Comment: Able to scan the WiFi around using Core WLAN. How to connect?